# typescript eslint parsing error "]" expected

Tags: typescript, eslint

Eslint unable to parse this typescript code.

```
export const swapKeyAndValue = <T extends { [index: string]: string }>(
    obj: T
) => {
    const newObj: { [prop: string]: string } = {}
    for (const prop in obj) {
        newObj[obj[prop]] = prop
    }
    return newObj as { [K in keyof T as T[K]]: K }
}
```

[image]

I cannot disable Eslint on this line, I have to exclude this file in Eslint config.

The code itself however works as expected.

Eslint config

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        es6: true,
        node: true,
    },
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:import/errors',
        'plugin:import/warnings',
        'plugin:import/typescript',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    ],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    ignorePatterns: [
        'dist/**/*', // Ignore built files.
    ],
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'import'],
    rules: {
        'import/no-unresolved': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'error',
        camelcase: 'off',
    },
}
```

typescript: 3.9.7
eslint: 7.32.0

Comment: Have you tried closing and re-opening your IDE?

Comment: I did, the error persist

Comment: Can you share your eslint config please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved by update `@typescript-eslint/parser` and `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` to 5.0.0

Comment: For me was to install "5.62.0" for both packages

Answer (score 2):

Without the eslint config, it's hard to say for sure, but it sounds like eslint doesn't know that you're using typescript, or doesn't know what specific typescript options / version you're using.

I would ensure that you are using the latest versions of eslint + your typescript-eslint plugins, and have something like this in your eslint config:

```
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  },
```

You can read more information about setting up eslint with typescript [here](https://learntypescript.dev/12/l3-eslint)

Comment: I already have this parser, eslint can parse the rest of my typescript with no problem, only this line has issue

Comment: eslint config shared

Comment: Thanks. I don't see the `parserOptions.project` set, which you will definitely need. Also make sure that you have the latest version of eslint and all of the dependent plugins / config packages.